# Authentication Types when switching from System.DirectoryServices to DirectoryServices.Protocols

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I need to know the equivalent AuthType values from AuthenticationTypes to migrate from S.DS to S.DS.P code.

I am rewriting an LDAP connection module that currently uses the System.DirectoryServices namespace. To increase compatibility with non-ActiveDirectory servers, I am trying to rewrite all of the code to use System.DirectoryServices.Protocols (as per the suggestion in "The .NET Developer's Guide to Directory Services Programming). Everything is going smoothly except for the transition between using the AuthenticationTypes enumeration to the AuthType one used by SD.Protocols. I need to know the equivalents between the two so that clients using the old code do not lose functionality when the new code is released.

The equivalencies that I know of are:
None -> Basic
Secure -> Negotiate (more or less)
Anonymous -> None
SecureSocketsLayer -> setting LdapSessionOptions.SecureSocketsLayer to true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you were on the right track.

After doing some research, I was able to map almost all of the AuthenticationTypes values:

None: AuthType.Basic

Secure: AuthType.Negotiate

Anonymous: AuthType.Anonymous

Signing: LdapSessionOptions.Signing

Sealing: LdapSessionOptions.Sealing

SecureSocketLayer: LdapSessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer

Encryption: Same value as SecureSocketLayer

ReadonlyServer: LdapSessionOptions.LocatorFlag.WriteableRequired = false

Serverbind: Use one of the LdapDirectoryIdentifier constructors that has the fullyQualifiedDnsHostName argument, with the value set to true.

FastBind: Doesn't apply, since this S.DS.P works at a lower level.

Delegation: No corresponding setting found. It could be that delegation is implicit. One way to test would be to convert the code on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and see if it works.

Be aware that not all non-AD servers will support AuthType.Negotiate, since it is Windows specific. There are several other things (like some of the LocatorFlag values) that will also not mean anything for non-AD systems. Thus, take care when converting code that assumed AD connectivity, since some assumptions will no longer be safe.

Comment: FastBind still applies, you use the method FastConcurrentBind() in the connection's SessionOptions. Great answer!

Comment: @Jakub - FastConcurrentBind is not the same as FastBind.  See [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx#sdspintro_topic6_perform)

Comment: It seems that according to [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), FastConcurrentBind and FastBind have the same base purpose (speeding up performance) although very good point, they do different things.

Comment: @Artomegus - I have a question on [authenticating on non-AD servers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48197277/153923) (Novell, specifically). You mentioned that `AuthType.Negotiate` is Windows specific. **Do you know what Novell would accept?**