Login system with LDAP
From [https://stackoverflow.com/q/48197277/5211833] on both Novell and Windows it seems to just define a connection to the LDAP domain server, I replicated what they said was correct:
this is my current code:
using System.Net;
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;


sso.Auth namespace
{
     public class LdapService
     {
         public bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
         {
             string ldap_server = "ldap://10.26.0.20:389";
             string ldap_domain = "siom";

             try
             {
                 using (var ldap_connection = new LdapConnection(ldap_server))
                 {
                     var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, ldap_domain);
                     ldap_connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
                     ldap_connection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
                     ldap_connection.Bind(networkCredential);
                 }
                
                 return true;

             } catch (LdapException ldapException)
             {
                 // Invalid credentials throw an exception with a specific error code
                 if (ldapException.ErrorCode.Equals(0x31))
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Displayed error 49 / 0x31");
                     Console.WriteLine($"{ldapException.Message}");
                     return false;
                 }
                 else if (ldapException.ErrorCode.Equals(0x51))
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Displayed error 81 / 0x51");
                     Console.WriteLine($"{ldapException.Message}");
                     return false;
                 }

                 Console.WriteLine($"It showed a different error:: {ldapException.ErrorCode}");
                 return false;
             }
         }
     }
}

I receive in the parameters the username and password of the person I want to authenticate, in this case, as code 81 (The LDAP server is unavailable) is being returned, should I initially pass the admin credentials and then authenticate my user that I receive?

Have you tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0
